# Why do I not see the button?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I'm setting an image for a button and it does not show up.
As far as I know setting it as backgroundImage will stretch it as the button's size hence I'd rather use setImage instead.

```
self.mainMapButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.mainMapButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map_icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.tabView addSubview:self.mainMapButton];
self.mainMapButton.center = CGPointMake((self.tabView.frame.size.width/4)/2, self.tabView.frame.size.height/2);
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you try with "backgroundImage"? And it shows up?

Comment: nope. but figured out why..

Comment: maybe frame is not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a silly suggestion, but don't you need to set the button frame?

```
self.mainMapButton.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 180.0, 100.0, 40.0);
```

Comment: Yeah I've figured that out on my own it's solved now.

Comment: He posted this exactly at the same time as I posted my own answer.. so I didn't feel the need but okay whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out if you don't set its frame it won't show up...
I assumed it would because UIImageView doesn't need frame setting and somehow because I'm setting an image.. thought it'd work the same but no.